# Trouble keeping transparency with upload script

Tags: php, image, image-uploading, uploading

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I thought I had this working perfectly until I uploaded a PNG with a transparent background, and it saved after with a black background. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Here is my image class and upload code. I thought the 'imagecreatefrompng' section was what would keep the transparency, but maybe I'm wrong or doing it wrong?

Image Class

```
    <?php
ini_set("memory_limit","50M");

function normal_resize_image($source, $destination, $image_type, $max_size, $image_width, $image_height, $quality){

    if($image_width <= 0 || $image_height <= 0){return false;} //return false if nothing to resize

    //do not resize if image is smaller than max size
    if($image_width <= $max_size && $image_height <= $max_size){
        if(save_image($source, $destination, $image_type, $quality)){
            return true;
        }
    }

    //Construct a proportional size of new image
    $image_scale    = min($max_size/$image_width, $max_size/$image_height);
    $new_width      = ceil($image_scale * $image_width);
    $new_height     = ceil($image_scale * $image_height);

    $new_canvas     = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height ); //Create a new true color image
    imagealphablending($new_canvas,true);

    //Copy and resize part of an image with resampling
    if(imagecopyresampled($new_canvas, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $image_width, $image_height)){
        save_image($new_canvas, $destination, $image_type, $quality); //save resized image
    }

    return true;
}

function thumb_resize_image($source, $destination, $image_type, $max_size, $image_width, $image_height, $quality){

    if($image_width <= 0 || $image_height <= 0){return false;} //return false if nothing to resize

    //do not resize if image is smaller than max size
    if($image_width <= $max_size && $image_height <= $max_size){
        if(save_image($source, $destination, $image_type, $quality)){
            return true;
        }
    }

    //Construct a proportional size of new image
    $image_scale    = min($max_size/$image_width, $max_size/$image_height);
    $new_width      = ceil($image_scale * $image_width);
    $new_height     = ceil($image_scale * $image_height);

    $new_canvas     = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height ); //Create a new true color image
    imagealphablending($new_canvas,true);

    //Copy and resize part of an image with resampling
    if(imagecopyresampled($new_canvas, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $image_width, $image_height)){
        save_image($new_canvas, $destination, $image_type, $quality); //save resized image
    }

    return true;
}

##### This function corps image to create exact square, no matter what its original size! ######
function crop_image_square($source, $destination, $image_type, $square_size, $image_width, $image_height, $quality){
    if($image_width <= 0 || $image_height <= 0){return false;} //return false if nothing to resize

    if( $image_width > $image_height )
    {
        $y_offset = 0;
        $x_offset = ($image_width - $image_height) / 2;
        $s_size     = $image_width - ($x_offset * 2);
    }else{
        $x_offset = 0;
        $y_offset = ($image_height - $image_width) / 2;
        $s_size = $image_height - ($y_offset * 2);
    }
    $new_canvas = imagecreatetruecolor( $square_size, $square_size); //Create a new true color image
    imagealphablending($new_canvas,true);

    //Copy and resize part of an image with resampling
    if(imagecopyresampled($new_canvas, $source, 0, 0, $x_offset, $y_offset, $square_size, $square_size, $s_size, $s_size)){
        save_image($new_canvas, $destination, $image_type, $quality);
    }

    return true;
}

##### Saves image resource to file ##### 
function save_image($source, $destination, $image_type, $quality){
    switch(strtolower($image_type)){//determine mime type
        case 'image/png': 
            imagepng($source, $destination); return true; //save png file
            break;
        case 'image/gif': 
            imagegif($source, $destination); return true; //save gif file
            break;          
        case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg': 
            imagejpeg($source, $destination, $quality); return true; //save jpeg file
            break;
        default: return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Here is the code to upload.

```
if(isset($_POST['addImages'])) {    
        $valid_formats = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "bmp", "JPG", "JPEG", "PNG", "GIF", "BMP");
        $max_file_size = 50971520; //50mb
        $path = "images/media/"; // Upload directory
        $count = 0;

        $thumb_square_size = 300; //Thumbnails will be cropped 
        $max_image_size = 1200; //Maximum image size (height and width)
        $thumb_prefix = "_thumb"; //Normal thumb Prefix
        $destination_folder = 'images/media/'; //upload directory ends with / (slash)
        $jpeg_quality = 90; //jpeg quality

        // Loop $_FILES to execute all files
        foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $foto => $name) {
            if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$foto] == 4) {
                continue; // Skip file if any error found
            }          
            if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$foto] == 0) {          
                if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$foto] > $max_file_size) {
                    $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                    continue; // Skip large files
                }
                elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                    $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                    continue; // Skip invalid file formats
                }
                else { // No error found! 
                    $image_name = $name; //file name
                    $image_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$foto]; //file size
                    $image_temp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$foto]; //file temp
                    $image_size_info = getimagesize($image_temp); //get image size

                    if($image_size_info){
                        $image_width = $image_size_info[0]; //image width
                        $image_height = $image_size_info[1]; //image height
                        $image_type = $image_size_info['mime']; //image type
                    } else {
                        die("Make sure image file is valid!");
                    }

                //switch statement below checks allowed image type as well as creates new image from given file.
                switch($image_type){
                    case 'image/png':
                        $image_res = imagecreatefrompng($image_temp);
                        imageAlphaBlending($image_res, true);
                        imageSaveAlpha($image_res, true);
                        break;
                    case 'image/gif':
                        $image_res = imagecreatefromgif($image_temp); break;            
                    case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg':
                        $image_res = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_temp); break;
                    default:
                        $image_res = false;
                }

                    if($image_res){
                        //Get file extension and name to construct new file name 
                        $image_info = pathinfo($image_name);
                        $image_extension = strtolower($image_info["extension"]); //image extension
                        $image_name_only = strtolower($image_info["filename"]);//file name only, no extension
                        $dateRec = date('d-M-Y-h-i-s');

                        //create a random name for new image (Eg: fileName_293749.jpg) ;
                        $new_file_name = $dateRec. '_' .  rand(0, 9999999999);
                        //folder path to save resized images and thumbnails
                        $thumb_save_folder  = $destination_folder . $new_file_name . $thumb_prefix . '.' . $image_extension ; 
                        $image_save_folder  = $destination_folder . $new_file_name. '.' . $image_extension;

                        //call normal_resize_image() function to proportionally resize image
                        if(normal_resize_image($image_res, $image_save_folder, $image_type, $max_image_size, $image_width, $image_height, $jpeg_quality)) {
                            //call crop_image_square() function to create square thumbnails
                            if(!thumb_resize_image($image_res, $thumb_save_folder, $image_type, $thumb_square_size, $image_width, $image_height, $jpeg_quality)) { 
                                die('Error Creating thumbnail'); 
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    $post_img = $new_file_name.'.'.$image_extension;
                    $post_img_thumb = $new_file_name.$thumb_prefix.'.'.$image_extension;
                    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO media_images(image, image_thumb, members_id) VALUES (?,?,?)');
                    $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $post_img, $post_img_thumb, $members_id);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();

                    $count++;
                }
            }
        }
        $MEMUS = memory_get_usage();
        ob_start();
        header("Location: media.php");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is fixed with the following.

```
  function resizeImage($source, $destination, $image_type, $max_size, $image_width, $image_height, $quality) {
                //RETURN FALSE IF NOTHING TO RESIZE
                if($image_width <= 0 || $image_height <= 0){return false;}

                //CHECK IF SMALLER THAN THE MAX SIZES
                if($image_width <= $max_size && $image_height <= $max_size) { //IF SMALLER THAN MAX SIZES
                    $new_width = $image_width;
                    $new_height = $image_height;
                } else { //ELSE CONSTRUCT PROPORTIONAL SIZE OF NEW IMAGE
                    $image_scale = min($max_size/$image_width, $max_size/$image_height);
                    $new_width = ceil($image_scale * $image_width);
                    $new_height = ceil($image_scale * $image_height);
                }

                $new_canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
                $black = imagecolorallocate($new_canvas, 0, 0, 0);
                imagecolortransparent($new_canvas, $black);
                imagealphablending($new_canvas,false);
                imagesavealpha($new_canvas, true);

                if(imagecopyresampled($new_canvas, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $image_width, $image_height)){
                    $this->save_image($new_canvas, $destination, $image_type, $quality);
                }
                return true;
            }
//Resize Image Normal
        function normal_resize_image($source, $destination, $image_type, $max_size, $image_width, $image_height, $quality) {
            //RETURN FALSE IF NOTHING TO RESIZE
            if($image_width <= 0 || $image_height <= 0){return false;}

            //CHECK IF SMALLER THAN THE MAX SIZES
            if($image_width <= $max_size && $image_height <= $max_size) { //IF SMALLER THAN MAX SIZES
                $new_width = $image_width;
                $new_height = $image_height;
            } else { //ELSE CONSTRUCT PROPORTIONAL SIZE OF NEW IMAGE
                $image_scale = min($max_size/$image_width, $max_size/$image_height);
                $new_width = ceil($image_scale * $image_width);
                $new_height = ceil($image_scale * $image_height);
            }

            $new_canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
            $black = imagecolorallocate($new_canvas, 0, 0, 0);
            imagecolortransparent($new_canvas, $black);
            imagealphablending($new_canvas,false);
            imagesavealpha($new_canvas, true);

            if(imagecopyresampled($new_canvas, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $image_width, $image_height)){
                $this->save_image($new_canvas, $destination, $image_type, $quality);
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Let me know if that works. Might need some tweaking for you.

Answer (score 1):

[You need to enable alpha and save the setting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php#43024)

```
    case 'image/png':
        $image_res =  imagecreatefrompng($image_temp);
        imageAlphaBlending($image_res, true);
        imageSaveAlpha($image_res, true);
        break;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I added the code in and it helped the with the main image in being transparent, but it didn't seem to help with the thumbnail being transparent. Did I do it right?

Comment: Not too sure on that one sorry, could be to do with passing in the quality attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use imagealphablending(). Put `imagealphablending($new_canvas,true);` after your `imagecreatetruecolor` command.

You need to use imagealphablending any time you create an image or layer as well. So in your upload you'll use it after your imagecreatefromX switch and after your imagecopyresampled calls as well.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I added the code in but it didn't seem to help with the thumbnail being transparent. Did I do it right?